If any url got response 401, i want to make token = null
axiosConfig.js
axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        const { response } = error;
        if (error.message === "Network Error") {
            alert("network error");
        }
        if (response.status === 401) {
            const{setToken} = useAuthContext();
            alert('unauthorized');
            localStorage.removeItem("ACCESS_TOKEN");
            setToken();
        }
        throw error;
    }
);

AuthContextProvider.jsx
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext({
    user: null,
    token: null,
    setUser: () => { },
    setToken: () => { }
});

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const [token, _setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN'));

    const setToken = (token) => {
        _setToken(token)
        if (token) {
            localStorage.setItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', token);
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
        }
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            user,
            token,
            setUser,
            setToken
        }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useAuthContext = () => useContext(AuthContext);

but this is not working. where is the problem

no error is showing in my browser console.
but still setToken(); is not working.

when any url will be get 401 unauthorized i want to make setToken() = null. is my code is ok

useAuthContext is a react hooks, you can't use hooks outside of react hooks or react components.
You should use store libs like zustand or use-one. Here I will choose use-one for the example:
import axiosClient from 'xior'; // or import axiosClient from 'axios';

import { setToken } from './useAuth';

axiosClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    const { response } = error;
    if (response?.status === 401) {
      alert('unauthorized');
      setToken('');
    }
    throw error;
  }
);

// useAuth.ts
import { create } from 'use-one';

const isBrowser = typeof document !== 'undefined';

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  token: isBrowser ? localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN') : '',
};

const [useAuth, authStore] = create(initialState);

export { useAuth, authStore, isBrowser };

export function setToken(token) {
  localStorage.setItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', token);
  authStore.setState((state) => ({
    ...state,
    token,
  }));
}

export function setUser(user) {
  authStore.setState((state) => ({
    ...state,
    user,
  }));
}


And you can use the useAuth hooks in react components for UI update:
import { useAuth, authStore } from './useAuth';
 
export default function TestCom() {
  const [state, setAuthState] = useAuth();
  // Same with: const state = authStore.getState();
  // setAuthState: authStore.setState

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}</pre>
}

